# friendly_id on profile using a param from user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, friendly-id

Im following the casts http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?autoplay=true  on friendly_id

Having a user model with field "login"
And a profile model with a "user_id" that belongs to user

How could I setup friendly_id so that it uses the login field from User model for its slug and get /profiles/1 to /profiles/username ( = login from User model )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friendly_id will use the column or method name you provide in friendly_id configuration. So, you can do this:

```
class Profile
  belongs_to :user

  friendly_id :profile_permalink, use: :slugged

  protected

  def profile_permalink
    user.login
  end

end
```

Comment: Installed all following instructions and in console User.find_each(:save) doesn't create the slugs. The def profile_permalink suggestions does not work either, I look into it later thx

Comment: Worked in the end was some strange issue with an outdated gem not sure wich one upgraded gems and restarted app made it work.

Comment: @fkreush the above method giving me error Couldn't find Profile with id=Usernam